# Should I implement user data sanitization/validation as middleware?

Tags: php, validation, middleware, slim, sanitization

I'm reimplementing my user management system with Slim, and I'm trying to figure out **where** I should do user data sanitization/validation.  I've been reading about middleware, and I'm wondering if this is an appropriate way to implement data validation.

My plan for validation is to use a validation schema (a simple JSON file) for each request that contains some user data (i.e., forms).  However, different forms will obviously use different schema, and there may be some types of validation that cannot be handled by the schema alone.

Thus, any middleware I implement will have to decide which schema to use based on the route.  Plus, some routes will require additional validation logic beyond that represented in the schema.  This to me sounds like the wrong approach though - isn't middleware supposed to be fairly "generic", performing the same logic on every request/response?

Another approach would be to have some sort of validation object that I initialize in each route with the appropriate schema, and then into which I inject my Slim app.

Which would be the more sensible approach?

Comment: I've not used Slim middleware. I'd imagine sanitisation (output) and validation (input) are use-case specific, and so would be _in_ your app and not in middleware? I tend to think of middleware as a plugin system, e.g. enforce SSL when signed in, which only needs broad context (in this case enabled status, signed-in status) rather than element-by-element settings.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is the sense I'm getting too.  It would be helpful if Slim documentation better described what types of things are/aren't appropriate for middleware.

Comment: Here's a [few Slim middlewares](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=slim+middleware) to look through, maybe they will give you a flavour of what can be done with it?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've successfully implemented CSRF protection using middleware.  It's a fine line...*slim* line, if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using global middleware doesn't make sense as you end up coupling every endpoint's parameter list together.

The two options I would consider are:

1. Implement as *route* middleware so that you can have different filtering/validation for each endpoint.

   e.g.

   ```
   function fooFilter() {
       // filter/validate GET variables here and set back into request.
   }

   $app->get('/foo', 'fooFilter', function () {
       // "controller" logic
   });
   ```

   The advantage of doing it this way is that your controller logic doesn't need to be cluttered up with validation stuff as that's already been done.
2. Filter/validate within the controller logic. The main advantage here is that you can more easily audit if a GET variable is being used without being filtered/validated first.